# The User Profile Service Failed the Logon. User Profile Cannot Be Loaded

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, exchange-2010

We have Windows 2008R2 with Exchange 2010. A user logged in and they receive a message `The User Profile Service Failed the Logon. User Profile Cannot Be Loaded.`

I can currently remote in as I have had a profile on there for a while now, but it is stopping anyone creating a new profile.

I have checked the registry HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList but there does not seem anything out of the norm, not .bak file etc.

I have also restarted the Server and applied updates.

Comment: Why are users logging on to the Exchange server?

Comment: Two Admin's need access for any server maintenance etc, why else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found a solution to my problem - the default user profile (`C:\Users\Default`) seemed to lack necessary ACEs. After resetting ACLs and re-enabling inheritance, creation of new profiles worked as expected. See [***this link***](http://www.shareitskills.com/the-user-profile-service-service-failed-the-logon/) for details.

Text of the above link:

I think the problem caused by some security permission changes to the default user account in the path C:\Users.

The solution, unhide Default user by doing (Computer -> Tools -> Folder options -> ) ,

The right click over the Default user -> Properties -> Security -> Advanced then tick the "replace all child object permission entries with inheritable permission from this object" fixes the issue. Basically you are replacing all child object permissions for Default user.

Now you should be able to login.

Answer (score 1):

Somehow folder C:\Users\Default was deleted from the server, so copying Default folder from another server solved my problem.

Comment: Not sure if it was the root cause in the OP's case though.

Comment: On our Server 2012 R2 machine C:\Users\Default was missing, we were able to copy it from another 2012 R2 server and it fixed this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried restoring ? Not sure if it would work on a server if it is recommended for a server but it did work on a Windows 7 machine. [Fixing The User Profile Service failed the logon](http://appuals.com/fixing-user-profile-service-failed-logon/)

Answer (score 0):

- If the error affects new users, the problem is in the default folder.
- If the error is in existing users, the problem will be in the current profiles.

To know which current profile corresponds to each user, we can check it in the following branch of the registry:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList
```

If we delete the user profile key and restart the computer, a new profile will be created using the default folder.

If the problem is in the default folder, we can copy it from another computer with the same operating system version, same language, same patches.

Extracted from: http://www.sysadmit.com/2017/01/windows-error-en-el-servicio-de-perfil-de-usuario-al-iniciar-sesion.html